# Select only when first select is null

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

I really dont get this, tried with coalesce() but with no result...

I have one select (very simplified to understand the problem):

```
select col1, 
       col2 
from   table1 t1 
where  table1.col1='value' 
       and table1.col2='value2' 
       and table1.col3='value3'
```

And i really need a result so if this select resultset is null (and **only if it is** null) (no result) then the following sql select came to picture

```
select col1, 
       col2 
from   table1 t1 
where  table1.col1='another_value' 
       and table1.col2='another_value2'
```

How can i get this two in to one big select? (any syntax which is recommended is appreciated...)

Comment: it can be, because i just wrote it to represent a problem (original select is so much complex than this), and thanks i will correct it!

Comment: What do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
; WITH Base AS (

    select col1, 
           col2 
    from   table1 t1 
    where  table1.col1='value' 
           and table1.col2='value2' 
           and table1.col3='value3'
)

, Base2 AS (

    select col1, 
           col2 
    from   table1 t1 
    where  table1.col1='another_value' 
           and table1.col2='another_value2'
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Base) -- HERE!!!

)

SELECT * FROM Base
UNION
SELECT * FROM Base2
```

and let's hope the SQL optimizer won't run the first query twice :-)
It is a CTE (Common Table Expression)... I used it so I could reuse the first query twice (one in the `EXISTS` and the other in the `SELECT ... UNION`)

By using a temporary table

```
select col1, 
       col2 
INTO   #temp1 -- HERE!!!
from   table1 t1 
where  table1.col1='value' 
       and table1.col2='value2' 
       and table1.col3='value3'

select col1, 
       col2 
from   table1 t1 
where  table1.col1='another_value' 
       and table1.col2='another_value2'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp1) -- HERE!!!
```

Comment: So sick, simplier solution?: ( 
without with? because i am not allowed to use it: S

I think with views it can also achieved?!

Comment: @czupe Yes, it would be the same. Why can't you use the `WITH`? Not `SQL Server`?

Comment: Oracle 10g, but it is our framework stuff and other devs do not use WITH in their sql-s (100 or more sql like this) but i will try it:) maybe our framework can understand it... Thanks again.

Comment: sorry but do not exactly get what you think in the term of 'TEMP TABLES' but we can say it like that, that we insert this to a temp table... But long story:)

Comment: It is working (anyway) so accepted it because i think you were the fastest

Comment: @czupe Otherwise there is the #temp table variant I just wrote... Be aware that #temp tables have a lifespan > query, so if necessary I can tell you how to drop it

Comment: Ok, thanks, but i dont want to use temporary table : ( views so much better or this With statement which live only in the live of the original query (i think)

Answer (score 1):

It could benefit us a little better if you had a little more information in your example. Is there a common value between the two tables that a JOIN can be established?

```
SELECT  col1 
        ,col2  
FROM    Table1 t1
WHERE  table1.col1='value' 
   and table1.col2='value2' 
   and table1.col3='value3'  
UNION 
SELECT  col1 
        ,col2
FROM    Table2 t2 
WHERE  table1.col1='another_value' 
   and table1.col2='another_value2'
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.Col1 = t2.Col2)
```

Comment: Added the WHERE clauses

Comment: Hmm, i thought about it, and dont get it, why would it work the t1.Col1 = t2.Col2 condition? What is the point? And i dont get Table2 in my example:)

Comment: This would be where the JOIN comes in. I am assuming there is a common value between the two tables. Am I correct?

Comment: Code you provide simple sample data in your example so I could better understand your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE, like this:

```
select COALESCE (
(select col1, 
       col2 
from   table1 t1 
where  table1.col1='value' 
       and table1.col2='value2' 
       and table1.col3='value3')
,
(select col1, 
       col2 
from   table1 t1 
where  table1.col1='another_value' 
       and table1.col2='another_value2')
)
```

Comment: UNION is not good, because it will have EVERY TIME the first AND second select result set, and i only want!!! FIRST OR SECOND select result set (most of the time the first and if it is null then the second). but thanks

Comment: tried already with  coalesce()  :(
but thanks!

"I really dont get this, tried with coalesce() but with no result..."

Answer (score 0):

Here are my ugly solution.

```
select top 1 with ties
       col1, 
       col2
from   table1 
where  (
          col1='value' 
          and col2='value2' 
          and col3='value3'
       ) OR
       (
          col1='another_value' 
          and col2='another_value2'
       )
order by 
          CASE
          WHEN col1='value' 
                 and col2='value2' 
                 and col3='value3'
            THEN 1
            WHEN col1='another_value' 
                 and col2='another_value2'
            THEN 2 END
```

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff917/1)**